# How to prevent added quotes in Order by in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am attempting to order by a column of type "character varying []" and cast it to an integer[] while sorting (instead of using the default ASCII comparison sort). I am using a Postgresql database.

I've found that the following query works as expected:

```
select <col> from <table> order by <col>::integer[] desc
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to programmatically do this in rails it is adding quotes around the column and casting suffix. This results in it thinking "::integer[]" is part of the column name - and of course there is no such column. Thus the query fails.

Here is the rails code:

```
scope.order([ '<col>::integer[]', 'desc', 'NULLS LAST' ].join(' '))
```

And this is the query it produces:

```
select <col> from <table> order by "<table>"."<col>::integer[]" desc
```

How can I implement this properly with rails?

Comment: `scope.order(Arel.sql("<col>::integer[] DESC NULLS last"))` should work.

Comment: @engineersmnky That, unfortunately, does not appear to have worked

Comment: Oh - but I did miss a detail in the above that may make a difference. I'm actually passing an array to the scope.order method, not just this single string. I'll need to modify the above to show that.

Comment: @engineersmnky Got it working based upon your answer - Thanks :) Had to use the Arel.sql() function around the entire order by string, after joining all the individual segments together. If you add an answer to the question I'll go ahead and accept it

Comment: @ryan, you started with their suggestion, but still had to do further learning to get the solution. You can post your own answer and accept it. If engineersmnky does post an answer, you can choose to accept theirs over yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @engineersmnky comment, I found the solution that I need in my code.

In the code I'm actually processing an array of columns (and directions) to sort by. It turns out the solution was indeed to use the `Arel.sql()` function to process the order by parameters prior to calling `scope.order()`, with the end result looking something like this:

```
def sort(scope, sorts)
  str = \
    sorts.map |sort| do
      col = get_sort_column_alias(sort[0])
      dir = sort[1]
      nullpos = (dir == 'asc') ? 'FIRST' : 'LAST'
      "#{col} #{dir} NULL #{nullpos}"
    end
  scope.order(Arel.sql(str))
end

def get_sort_column_alias(col)
  case col
  when 'target' then 'target::integer[]'
  ...
  else col
  end
end
```